# How to write equals for value-based classes of 2 different types?

Tags: java

In the [Java 8 definition of value-based classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html) you can read:

> have implementations of `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString` which are computed solely from the instance's state and not from its identity or the state of any other object or variable;

But if you wanna compare fields in `equals(Object o)` you have to cast the `o` to a specific implementation otherwise it's **not** possible to access `o`'s fields.

I've noticed that JDK value-based classes like Optional or YearTime also compare against type (`if !(obj instanceof Optional)`).

Is it possible to create all value-based classes in Java so that **2 different types** are "**computed solely from the instance's state and not from its identity**"?

EDIT

If it's not possible to satisfy the condition, IMHO, this condition should be removed from the definition because it's not possible to implement it in Java 11-.

EDIT 2

It's possible to satisfy the condition. I know now. However, it will not be possible to make 2 instances of 2 different types that have the very same field to be equal using `equals(Object o)`.

```
final class A {
    final Integer field = Integer.valueOf(1);

    private A() {}

    public static A create(){
        return new A();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        
        final A other = (A) o;
        return field.equals(other.field);
    }
}

final class B {
    final Integer field = Integer.valueOf(1);

    private B() {}

    public static B create(){
        return new B();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        
        final B other = (B) o;
        return field.equals(other.field);
    }
}
```

`A.create().equals(B.create())` will never be true since it is not possible to write `equals` that would compare values only.

Comment: Checking the parameter's type and casting is not "based on identity".

Comment: `instanceof` is not directly related to identity. For example, `"foo" instanceof String` and `"bar" instanceof String` are both true, but they're not identical. To put this another way, `a == b => (a instanceof T) == (b instanceof T)`, but not the other way around.

Comment: How do you know a class is Value-based or not. A value-based class is a theoretical concept. So to identify that you can create interface/annotation which will be implemented/annotated on valued based class

Comment: Also: "you have to cast the o to a specific implementation" No, you could cast to an interface type, for example if you were comparing two `List`s for equality.

Comment: I wanted to ask the questions as "How to write equals for value-based classes of 2 different types?". Sorry for confusing you.